# qtcreator desktop kit is greyed out

Tags: qt

Its been quite a while since my last raspberry pi project. I went ahead and bought a new Rpi 4B and  installed a fresh Raspbian OS on it and installed qt the way i remember it

```
$ sudo apt-get install qt5-default  #This does not work anymore i used an alternative
$ sudo apt-get install qtcreator
$ sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev
```

But its not as straight forward as i remember it anymore.

when i created a qt Application the desktop kit is greyed out

[image]

And upon further investigation it would seems that i do not have a qt version

[image]

Under the qt Version tab i dont have an item listed. How do i add a qt  version?

[image]

It ask for a qmake executable and i do not know where its path is

Comment: `qt version` is the version of installed Qt

Comment: @jsotola there is no option to pick/write anything. adding a version will ask for a file. where is that file?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake.html

Comment: @jsotola yes i have read that guide, my problem is in the step `2.Select the qmake executable for the Qt version that you want to add.` I do not know where that location is in my pi directory. Both options of "Add" and "Link with Qt" asks for a file/directory that i do not know where it is

Comment: then, why is your title `qtcreator desktop kit is greyed out` ... it would make more sense to be `how to find qmake executable?`

Comment: @jsotola that is indeed true, but solving the qt version might not resolve why the desktop kit is greyed out. It is only _what I think_ would solve the problem

Comment: To list installed packages, use "apt list --installed | grep -i qt" (about 60 on bullseye).  To see all qt packages remove "--installed" (more than 700 packages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by first running

```
$ which qmake
```

it should show you a location of qmake, now go to

```
Tools > Options > Kits > Qt version > Add
```

On the pop up, navigate to qmake location and then add. Now go back to

```
Tools > Options > Kits > Kit > scrool to qt version > qt 5  should now be an option there.
```

Although you may now solved the desktop app being grey, the project i had doesnt run because of clang. Just go ahead and install that one too

```
$ sudo apt install clang
```

Comment: this hasn't worked for me.  i installed latest raspi 64 bit os (regular non minimal) on my raspi 4b
  
Linux raspberrypi 5.15.32-v8+ #1538 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 31 19:40:39 BST 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux

I've tried sudo apt install qtcreator and the menu / preferences / add/remove software - search qtcreator, check, apply
   
qmake is in the path, but when i Add it, it's a softlink that points to a nonexistent binary
   
is there something else i need to sudo apt install?  build-essential is already there.  and several libqt5*5 libraries are installed with qtcreator